# Pointers c++ : ask address gives value?

Tags: c++, pointers

I was confused by this piece of code I recently saw on stackoverflow. The return value must be IntArray& (so an address, right?). But then he returns *this (a value, right?). This seems not logic to me.. This question could be a duplicate but i didn't found it so very sorry if it is.
Here is the code:

```
IntArray& IntArray::operator=(const IntArray& other){
     if(this == &other){
         return *this;
     }
     ...
}
```

Comment: Read about *references* in C++. The `&` in reference syntax has absolutely no relation to "address-of" operator and/or pointers. No, it does not mean that the return value is an address. References is a very broad topic, which cannot be taught in single a SO answer. Open you favorite C++ book.

Comment: First step - learn the language.

Answer (score 2):

Your confusion is all due to `IntArray&`, which is not an address, it's a *reference*.

While it is true that `operator&` (unless overloaded) usually yields a pointers in an expression like `&value`, in this case `&` in any generatic `T&` (for some type `T`) has nothing to do with that operator, it's associated with the type.

In a similar way, `T&&` is an *rvalue reference* to `T`.

In your specific instance, then:

```
IntArray& IntArray::operator=(const IntArray& other){
     if(this == &other){
         return *this;
     }
     ...
}
```

you have that `this` is a pointer to `IntArray`, and by dereferencing it with `operator*` you are obtaining an `IntArray&` value, which matched perfectly with the return type of that function.

Comment: but I learned on college that if you make a reference ex. 'int &ex = d;' 
then '&ex' will give the adress of d and 'ex' will give the value..

Comment: @GNIUS Either you are mistaken with `int* ex = &d;` or your college tought you wrong. In `int& ex = d;` you are *aliasing* `d` with the reference `ex`.

Comment: @GNIUS [cppreference page about references](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) also the usage of `&` inside a *declaration* is different than its usage ([operator&](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access)) inside an *expression* (and jeffrey is right)

Comment: now your pointing to a reference? ex points to the value where d reference? i don't get it. I thought i finally understood everything :(

Comment: @GNIUS `int* ex = &d;` is not a pointer to a reference.  `int* ex = &d;` means create a pointer to an int called ex (`int* ex`)  and set it to the address of (`&`) d.  `&` in c++ is used for references and it is the [address of](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64sa8b1e.aspx) operator

Comment: @NathanOliver, i undestand. In this site (http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/74a-returning-values-by-value-reference-and-address/) they return just value when &object is expected? is it fault to return &this?

Comment: @GNIUS: Your college taught you wrong. Or, rather, it misled you. It seems your professor was hung up on antiquated "declaration mirrors use" comprehension tricks that just don't work in real life, certainly not in this century. If you make a reference, e.g. `int& ex = d`, then `ex` is a reference. And using it gives you the value of the referee. `&ex` gives you the address of `d` but this meaning of `&` is completely unrelated.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit what is the meaning of & here? After reading/learning i think : it means it is a reference to an IntArray object. if you return *this, it returns the value where *this to referee. Is this right?

Comment: @GNIUS I would recommend starting from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31946885/pointers-c-ask-adress-gives-value/31946902?noredirect=1#comment51805595_31946885). Learn the language again, maybe via some of [these awesome books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). When `&` is used near a type, it's usually a reference, when it's used in front of a value, then it's `operator&` (which is the "take the address" operator). I cannot explain it better than this, sorry.

Comment: @GNIUS: `*this` is actually not a reference :)